# Разделить сумму на слагаемые рандомно

Tags: php

Задача: разделить сумму 70 на 8 слагаемых рандомно, минимальное слагаемое: 6, максимальное: 15. Нужно чтобы ни одно из слагаемых не было ниже минимального и не выше максимального. Получим слагаемые: 10, 6, 7, 15, 7, 9, 10, 6. Имеется код:

```
function splitSum($sum, $count, $minPrice, $maxPrice) {
  $prices = array();

  if($sum > $count * $maxPrice || $sum < $count)
    throw new \Exception('Wrong sum for split');

  $j = 0;
  for($i = $count - 1; $i > 0; $i--) {
    $diff = $sum - $i * $maxPrice;

    if($diff > 0)
      $prices[$j] = rand($minPrice, $maxPrice);
    else {
      if($sum - $i * 1 > $maxPrice)
        $max = $maxPrice;
      elseif($sum - $i * 1 <= 0)
        $max = $sum;
      else
        $max = $sum - $i * 1;

      $prices[$j] = rand($minPrice, $max);
    }

    if($i > 1)
      $sum -= $prices[$j];

    $j++;
  }
  $prices[$j] = $sum - $prices[$j - 1];

  return $prices;
}
```

Функция подбирает слагаемые, но минимальная граница не соблюдается.

Comment: `if($sum > $count * $maxPrice || $sum < $count)` забыли умножить на `$minPrice` и внутри цикла вместо проверки `$diff = $sum - $i * $maxPrice; if($diff > 0)` видимо следует делать проверку `if($sum > $i * $maxPrice || $sum < $i * $minPrice)` и перегенерировать слагаемое в случае `true`.

Comment: @Visman, помогла замена множителя на $minPrice и проверка

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Рабочий код:

```
function splitSum($sum, $count, $minPrice, $maxPrice) {
  $prices = array();

  if($sum > ($count * $maxPrice) || $sum < $count || $sum < ($count * $minPrice))
    throw new \Exception('Wrong sum for split');

  $j = 0;
  for($i = $count - 1; $i > 0; $i--) {
    $diff = $sum - $i * $maxPrice;

    if($diff > 0)
      $prices[$j] = rand($minPrice, $maxPrice);
    else {
      if(($sum - ($i * $minPrice)) > $maxPrice) $max = $maxPrice;
      elseif(($sum - ($i * $minPrice)) <= 0) $max = $sum;
      else $max = $sum - ($i * $minPrice);

      $prices[$j] = rand($minPrice, $max);
    }

    if($i > 1)
      $sum -= $prices[$j];

    $j++;
  }
  $prices[$j] = $sum - $prices[$j - 1];

  return $prices;
}
```